# Asp.Net MVC bundle is not getting refreshed

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am using Asp.Net MVC bundling, but one of my css bundle is not getting reflected on change. The updated file is on server.

the url for bundle is like:
              http://example.com/Bundles/MyBundledScripts

but I think it should be like :
              http://example.com/Bundles/MyBundledScripts?v=ILpm9GTTPShzteCf85dcR4x0msPpku-QRNlggE42QN81

The trailing hashcode is not getting appended in the url.

Would you please tell me the root cause why this hashcode is not getting appended in the url?

Thanks,
Sombir

Comment: On the project you run do you have `compilation debug="true"` ? If so try setting it to false or run your project in `Release` for first try.

Comment: No I have debug = false. and I have ran the project in release mode.

Comment: Great. Did you try to set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` somewhere in your composition root (eg. App_start)?

Comment: In my local it was but in server where I am getting the error it is commented

Comment: my file is getting bundled and minified, but the url is not correct and changes are not reflecting

Comment: I have checked it is not there.

Comment: I meant you should try have it not commented out, but make sure that command gets executed.

Comment: I have un-commented the line but still getting the same url.